# how to find the excluded value of a fraction that consist of numbers only?

Tags: rational-numbers

I am trying to solve a worksheet that has questions related to Rational Expressions and one of the questions in that worksheet asks us to simplify and find the excluded value of a rational expression.
I got to solve a question that was:-
[Rational Expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHiYa.jpg)

As I Simplified I the above rational Expression I got:-
[Simplified Expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aBhP.jpg)

Now I know that if want to find the excluded value than I need to make the denominator equal to zero and I would get the excluded value that is {0, -5} without simplifying but I would like to know that if I do simplify than is there any way that I can get the excluded value from the simplified expression.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can factor out $\frac23$ in the numerator.

$$\frac{\frac23\cdot (3a^2+15a)}{3a^2+15a}=\frac23 \ \ \forall a \in  \mathbb R \backslash \{0, -5\}$$

Comment: I got it that if I do factor out in the numerator somehow I will get the excluded value by making the denominator equal to zero but my question is that suppose if I am given the question such as find the excluded value of the expression/fraction "2/3" than is there any way to find the excluded value of expression/fraction "2/3"?

Comment: You have the equation $x\cdot (3a^2+15a)=2a^2+10a$ Now you can split the equation in two equations: $x\cdot 3a^2=2a^2$ and $x\cdot 15a=10a$. Both equations have to be fullfilled.